# Ошибка Invalid typecast при компиляции под x64 платформу

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Имеется следующий код (под x32 компилируется, Delphi XE7):

```
const

varTypeMask = $0FFF;


TExtData = packed record
VExtType: LongWord;
Reserved: LongWord;
VPointer: Pointer;
Dummy: LongWord;
end;


function ExtType(const Value: Variant): LongWord;
begin
  if TVarData(Value).VType and varTypeMask <> 0 then
    Result := TVarData(Value).VType
  else
    Result := TExtData(Value).VExtType;
end;
```

При компиляции под x64 имеем ошибку:

```
[dcc64 Error]: E2089 Invalid typecast
```

с ссылкой на строку: `Result := TExtData(Value).VExtType;`

Как исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, что для x64 размер типа `Variant` и, соответственно, `TVarData` в байтах отличается от размера этих типов при компиляции под x32. Посмотрите определение `TVarData`. При компиляции под x32 размер `TVarData` 16 байт, а для x64 он 24 байта.

```
TVarData = packed record
  case Integer of
  ...
  1: (RawData: array [0..{$IFDEF CPUX64}5{$ELSE}3{$ENDIF}] of LongInt);
```

По этому, чтобы исправить ошибку, нужно исправить определение `TExtData` так, чтобы при компиляции под x64 он был размером в 24 байта, а при компиляции под x32 по прежнему 16 байт, тогда компилятор всегда сможет интерпретировать `Variant` как `TExtData`.

Исправить можно, например, вот так:

```
TExtData = packed record
  VExtType: LongWord;     // 4
  Reserved: LongWord;     // 4
  VPointer: Pointer;      // 4/8
  DummyPointer: Pointer;  // 4/8
end;                      // 16/24
```